# Is it possible to use relative path in ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse?

Tags: apache, proxy, apache2, reverse-proxy

For example there is following configuration in httpd.conf:

```
ProxyPass app   http://somehost:someport/App_1   
ProxyPassReverse app   http://somehost:someport/App_1
```

Now I should use absolute urls to forward requests from "/myapp" to "/app":

```
<Location /myapp >   
   ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/app
   ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/app
</Location>
```

Is it possible to use relative path in ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse?

```
<Location /myapp >  
   ProxyPass /app  
   ProxyPassReverse /app  
</Location>
```

Answer (score 4):

No.

The [apache docs about ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) says the target must be a URL. If you try to put something that isn't a URL (like `/app`), you get the following error:

> ProxyPass URL must be absolute!

You should look into [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) instead. It can rewrite requests on the serverside without redirecting the browser. Giving your /myapp -> /app example, some simple rules such as this would suffice:

```
RewriteRule ^/myapp /app [L]
```

Comment: Why it is possible to use construction with balancer? ProxyPass balancer://app. Or balancer://app - it is URL?

Comment: Yes, `balancer://app` is a URL. It maps to a bunch of members, like `ajp://app.domain.com` which are also URLs. Of course, `ftp://some.host.com/dir` is also a URL, but it's not supported in ProxyPass.

Comment: how about ProxyPassMatch?