# Apache ProxyPass with url path

Tags: apache, jboss, wildfly, virtualhost, proxypass

I have a domain name e.g. **example.com** and its pointed to a jboss server

When i accessing https://example.com, its working fine.

The application is deployed in root path.(i.e. context-root is "/")

its pointed to a jboss server through apache proxy.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"

    ProxyPass / https://10.xx.0.6:8443/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://10.xx.0.6:8443/

    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Another web app ("otherapp") is deployed on the same jboss server. context-root is "/otherapp"
Then i want to access the web app through the url like this "https://example.com/otherapp/" or "https://otherapp.example.com/"

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache's **<Location>** directive

```
...
    <Location /otherapp>
        ProxyPass https://10.xx.0.6:8443/
        ProxyPassReverse https://10.xx.0.6:8443/
    </Location>
```

More help here: [Is it possible to use relative path in ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853077/is-it-possible-to-use-relative-path-in-proxypass-proxypassreverse)

Apache docs (take note of the trailing slash): https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location